# SQL if date is within a week

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a field called `Date` in my SQL table. Type `DATE`with format `2016-05-31`. What I need to do is `SELECT ..... WHEN`Date`= in a week back from current date`, so that only the entries from the last week, are shown. How could I achieve this?

Comment: ``date` >= dateadd(sysdate() - interval 1 WEEK)`

Answer (score 3):

Dates are ordinal data types, so you can use the `between` operator on it:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND 
                      CURRENT_DATE()
```